# How can I convince TypeScript that I am getting [number, number] back from this chain?

Tags: typescript

I'm still getting used to TypeScript and I should probably relent on my desire to have these defined as paired numbers. At the same time, I really want to understand how to coerce TypeScript into cooperating with me on this.

For context, I'm running a MongoDB geospatial `$geoWithin` query that expects queries to be structured something like `coordinates: [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] ]`. As such, I structured my interface to look like `[number, number][][]`

I'm parsing the data coming in from a query string. I split the sets of pairs by `;` and   the pair itself by `,` so the above would be `0,0;3,6;6,1;0,0`

The code works, so far as I am aware (I need to thoroughly test it but I've been wrestling with the typing). I just can't get TypeScript to trust that the results will be what I want them to be.

```
const parsed: [number, number][] = input
  .split(';')
  .map(pairs =>
    pairs
      .split(',')
      .map(val => Number.parseFloat(val))
      .filter(val => val !== NaN)
  )
  .filter(pair => pair.length === 2);
```

And the error:

```
Type 'number[][]' is not assignable to type '[number, number][]'.
Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TS static analysis has done its best effort to tell that expression's return type is `number[][]`. So at this point you'll need to manually tell TS more information with *type assertion*, using the `as` keyword.

```
const parsed: [number, number][] = input
  .split(';')
  .map(pairs =>
    pairs
      .split(',')
      .map(val => Number.parseFloat(val))
      .filter(val => val !== NaN)
  )
  .filter(pair => pair.length === 2) as [number, number][];
```

I personally will simply write `as any`, for being practical.